# Cordova CLI Lifecycle - Hooks Order

Tags: cordova

In which order are the hooks in cordova executed?

I can't find a reliable source for the order of hooks. All I've found was a alphabetical list of hooks: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a part inside the documentation (nearly at the top) which tells you in which order the hooks are executed:

> Hook scripts could be defined by adding them to the special predefined
>   folder (/hooks) or via configuration files (config.xml and plugin.xml)
>   and run serially in the following order:
>
> Application hooks from /hooks; Application hooks from config.xml;
>   Plugin hooks from plugins/.../plugin.xml. Note: /hooks directory is
>   considered deprecated in favor of the hook elements in config.xml and
>   plugin.xml.

The single hooks inside your config.xml will of course be executed from the top to the bottom of your document. :)